# namespace or class could not be found (ASP.NET WebSite "project")

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I am currently trying to cleanup a bit of a corporate website that I inherited here. I managed to clean up most of the errors in the website but something is still up here.

I have one masterpage that have this code :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
    public lists m_listsClass = new lists();
```

(no it's not a typo the S in lists).

Now in App_code I have one class lists.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for lists
/// </summary>
public class lists
{
    public lists()
    {
```

When I try to build the website in visual studio 2008 I have this error :

```
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'lists' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\egirard\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\iFuzioncorp\iFuzioncorp\Masters\MasterPage.master.cs 23  12  iFuzioncorp
```

Am I missing something ?

Also I saw some strange behaviour on the server. Apparently according to IIS7 it is compiling using .net 2.0 (the pool is configured with .net 2) but there are some `"using`" statements that include Linq ... how is it possible to compile the page if Linq is not part of the .net 2 itself ?

Just edited with news details on the code itself. No namespace at all everywhere.

Comment: @Erick: you missed telling everyone this is a web site "project". These are not projects, and are different from every other kind of code in Visual Studio.

Comment: @John it's a web application project.

Comment: @Erick: ok, then please stop saying web site. :-) Also, it's very strange that there are no namespaces and that you're using App_Code. Is there a .csproj file?

Comment: @John, actually the web app has been subcontracted and then uploaded via ftp ... I do not have any .csproj originally made (if there was any) I created a project from scratch and imported files. It's compiling 100% ok on the server side, only on my workstation I've got warnings and errors....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I understood quite lately that it was a *website* and not a *web application* I had to question the guys here to get it... So it's quite normal all the error I had. I haven't had the occasion to convert it first.

Answer (score 14):

Hi There – i had a similar problem; all my namespaces and inheritance was in place. Then i then noticed that the class file’s build action was set to “Content” not “Compile” (in the properties window.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever worth might there be for an answer (possibly not the right one) after many months, i think i should contribute this:

There is a case that this happens, when you place a web site inside another (ie in a subfolder). 
In that case, the only App_Code folder that is legitimate is the App_code folder of the outer web site. That is, the App_Code folder right under the root of the master web site.

Maybe (say maybe) there should be no need to transform your web site to a web application, if you place the class file inside the App_code folder of the ROOT web site.

Answer (score 1):

include the namespace under which lists calss is defined

or

define both the master page and lists class under the same namespace

Comment: there is no namespace defined for the list class itself and the masterpage

Comment: does your master page inherits from another class?

Comment: wrap the lists class under a namespace and include it in the masterpage

Comment: @youssef the typical System.Web.UI.MasterPage

Comment: namespace MyNamespace{
public class lists
{
    public lists()

.....

using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using MyNamespace;

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {

    {

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your masterpage, you have an #include statement for the namespace that the lists class is a part of (if they're in seperate namespaces, the masterpage isn't going to automatically pick up on it).

As for the strange server side behavior, .NET 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 all run inside of .NET 2.0 app pools in IIS. It looks strange at first, but you get used to it. Here's a link with a little more in-depth explination:

[The Way I See It: Where is ASP.NET 3.5 on IIS?](http://blogs.msdn.com/vijaysk/archive/2008/03/20/running-asp-net-3-5-on-iis.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a type, you must reference the assembly which defines it and include the appropriate namespace.

Using only includes namespaces, if you don't use any types from said namespaces it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

is lists.cs wrapped in a namespace? if it is the case then you need to add the namespace (yournamespace.lists) or include it in masterpage. Check Also if your MasterPage is in a Namespace

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify the Build Action of the App_Code Class to Compile.
2. Clean and Build the Project

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself

It wasn't working because the project I was referencing was set as a console application in its properties instead of a class library