# VS2010 refuses to compile a namespace, says it doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I transferred my project into another computer from Win XP to Win 7. After installation, I realized that something in my App_code folder, called like mydata.web.utils namespace, has a class called like WebConstants (which is public class and public functions).

now in areas like global.asax, it tells me "WebConstants does not exist in this context"

Even though I have:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="mydata.web.utils" %>
```

And webconstants.cs has:

```
namespace mydata.web.utils
{
  public class WebConstants
  {
   public static String APPLICATION_VERSION = "version";
  ........
  }
}
```

No syntax errors or compiler errors in webconstants.cs

But everywhere else, it's saying "what is 'web'"??

If I rename the namespace from "web.utils" to just "web", still same problem. If I rename "web.utils" to "wez"--then the compiler errors go away.

But I cannot do this, because then I'd have to change it all over the project, which is a ton of work.

I also notice in the "build output" that there is no App_code being compiled in the project. Maybe because it's an ASP.net folder, I'm not certain. Is that normal?

How is it that the same source code, same visual studio, produces errors in win7 and no errors in the winXP computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the webcontants.cs file and go to Properties. Check to be sure 'Build Action' is set to 'Compile'. It may be set to 'Content', in which case VS wouldn't pick it up.

Comment: There is on right click properties in VS 2010 :S. What do I do?

Comment: There should always be a properties selection in Solution Explorer when you right click. Try selecting the webconstants.cs file in Solution Explorer and hitting Alt-Enter, assuming you haven't changed keybindings.

Comment: As an aside, I'm almost 100% positive this is your problem. You may want to figure out how to check the Build Action in VS before you spend time pursuing other issues. This is a common scenario with adding class files to the App_Code folder (which probably shouldn't be used anyways, but that's another discussion).

Comment: Well there is a properties window. And it says "full name", "full path", and "custom tool", that's it. Nothing about "build action". Nothing in right click or properties window that has that option.

Comment: Then there's some other issue you have going on. All .cs files in Visual Studio should have a Build Action property. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx. "You can select any file in Solution Explorer and then examine its properties in the Properties window. Visual Basic and Visual C# files have four properties: File Name, Build Action, Custom Tool, and Custom Tool Namespace."

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have that. http://imgur.com/9qy3M  What's wrong with my Visual Studio?  CS files in my other project within the same solution does have Build Action property. The stuff in App_code or anywhere else in that first project, files like "bla.aspx.cs" does not have that option.

Comment: Try deleting the file and recreating it in Visual Studio maybe. Not sure why Build Action wouldn't be there. Try posting another SO question on that subject if deleting/recreating doesn't work. Once you get the property to show up, I'll bet you the Build Action is set to Content and that setting it to Compile solves your problem.

Comment: Creating a blank class anywhere in that first ASP.net website project, doesn't show build action. I guess it's because ASP.net projects aren't the same as C# projects?

Comment: The image you linked states that webcontent.cs is a "Web File" as seen in the properties window. This indicates that you probably have your project configured as a web site, not a web application although I'm not positive about that. You may want to convert it to a web application (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx) and then modify the Build Action. Not sure at this point how you have your solution set up.

Comment: I see but before that I'd like to find out for sure if this is the problem. Here's a small test I did. I built a file called TEEST.cs. I put it in namespace trout.net.cool.treat and in App_code folder. (totally made up) Then in global.asax I did <%@ Import Namespace="trout.net.cool.treat" %>    Finally, I called TEEST n = new TEEST();  And it says, I'm missing a reference to this and could not be found. How come this is happening? Before it wasn't like this.

Comment: I had a similar problem as Dexter, but didn't realize that I just needed to scroll up to the top of the list. When I clicked "Properties", it sent me to the File Name field, so the Build Action field was simply out of view.

Answer (score 3):

If you have this namespace in a different project, make sure you are adding the reference to the web project as well.

Also, make sure that the project where the namespace "mydata.web.utils" is coming from, is being build properly.

You can also change the level of the details in your "output" window in Visual Studio, after the build fails: (Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Build and Run, selecting “Normal”, in order to see more details). You can get more details on this from my blog on this: [Error “ILMerge.Merge: The target assembly ‘blabla.blabla’ lists itself as an external reference” building a setup project](http://blog.robertolopes.com/2010/12/21/error-ilmerge-merge-the-target-assembly-blabla-blabla-lists-itself-as-an-external-reference-building-a-setup-project/)

Comment: webconstants.cs and global.asax are in the same project. It also doesn't recognize web.utils even in the same App_code folder in other files. I'll try your last paragraph.

Comment: Also I wanted to mention for all... That although I see 8 errors in "error list" as I described above. Under Build, both projects compile successfully without failure. Could very well be a bug in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Your blog responds with a status 500

Answer (score 1):

Ok reading your commments in the other answer below made me understand whats going on...

Please see this link: 
[namespace or class could not be found (ASP.NET WebSite "project")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044972/namespace-or-class-could-not-be-found-asp-net-website-project)

You need to convert the current project which is an asp.net **website** to a **web application**.

Comment: Definitely something I would do, but maybe when I have more time. It could be a lot of work converting everything.

Comment: I don't think it would actually take a lot of work, there is an option when you right click on the website to convert to webapplication

Answer (score 1):

Did you try building the project? Did you verify if there was any missing DLL references in your project after loading?

Comment: In the other project (2 projects in the solution) there are 3 references warning that it couldn't find the dll. But they are there, and it's just a warning.

Comment: @Dexter, that means that vs couldn't find the reference dll. Just remove those references that have a warning and re-reference them back in your project. It should then compile successfully and you should be good to go.

Comment: Whatever the bug was, something about getting the DLLs referenced correctly (or dereferenced), and removing and modifying some of the assembly, and reinstalling ajax toolkit, somehow, it fixed itself. The error just disappeared by its own.