# Reference disappear upon debug/build (C#, VB.NET, VS2010)

Tags: c#, reference, visual-c#-express-2010

I am using the `MagicLibrary` for a few components. I knew it was written in Visual Studio 2003 and recompiled it in Visual C# Express 2010. It compiled just fine and I could see the library in the folder.

I then created a new project in Visual C# Express 2010 and added the components `MagicalLocalLibrary.dll` to the Toolbox. They appeared fine with no errors. I put in a control from the Toolbox to my form, and it seemed fine. I then debugged (to see if any errors would occur) and I saw that the reference `MagicalLibrary` disappeared and I got the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Crownwood' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The thing is that, the reference shows fine under References in Solution Explorer but I can't import it with `using` or use it in the code (simply is not listed in InstelliSense either) but if i go into the Object Browser and choose "My Solution" it is not listed. I can click on the Reference in Solution Explorer and just change the Copy Local property to True or False, then it will appear in the Object Browser but whenever I debug my project again it disappear.

Any idea why it does this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check that you are using the .Net 4 framework and not the client profile version

You find that setting when you right-click on your project, choose properties. And under application there is a setting for target framework. If you have chosen the .Net 4 framework Client Profile, then this behavior that you described can happen

Comment: Thank you, Bassetassen - I always forget that! Oh, do you know if it is possible to set a default framework when you create a new project?

Comment: @Humanoidism Your welcome, done the same thing many times myself. In this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4595212/797672) there are some suggestions on how to change the default

Comment: In VS2010 the Target Framework setting is found from the Compile tab, at the bottom of another pop-up dialog from the Advanced Compile Options button. And thanks! We had a few projects in a solution and the references between them were getting lost. Setting the target framework away from the Client Profile one fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a very similar issue once.  In my case the problem turned out to be a missing dependency for the "vanishing" namespace's assembly.  What finally gave me the information I needed was the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785302/vs2010-refuses-to-compile-a-namespace-says-it-doesnt-exist/4785507#4785507) StackOverflow answer to raise the MSBuild output verbosity level.  After raising the verbosity setting the IDE should give you a more specific reason why the compilation fails.