# Visual Studio shows thousands of reference errors that are the result of a single build error when mixing new and old CSPROJ format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a project which references several sub projects

```
MainProject -> Library1
            -> Library2 -> Library3


NetProject  -> Library1
            -> Library2 -> Library3
```

If I make a single typo build error in Library 3, every single reference to Library2 or Library3 show ups as "blah" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Once I track down the real error, all the missing reference errors disappear.

Sometimes making a single typo in Library3 will make Library3 disappear from the references in Library2. When I right click "Add Reference" the reference is there and ticked but it cannot be seen. Removing and adding the reference fixes the problem.

All 5 projects reference 4.6.1

Library1,2 and 3 use the new CSPROJ format.

MainProject is a WPF project and use the old CSPROJ format.

WebProject is a netcore project (targetting 461) and uses the new CSPROJ format.

Here is an example of the CSPROJ for library1,2,3

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Deterministic>False</Deterministic>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

I have tried multiple versions of Visual Studio Enterprise (15.5 preview, 15.4 etc)

Why do I get these chain effect build errors?

Why do the references disappear and require reloading?

edit: If I change Library1,2,3 to the old CSPROJ format the problem goes away. It only appears to happen as a result of mixing the old and new CSPROJ format. New being the NETCORE style csproj, old being the older style where each file has to be individually referenced etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do I get these chain effect build errors?

Since Library3 is at the root of the dependency tree i.e. other projects depend on this getting successfully built, so any build errors within library3 will cause the dll to be not made, hence missing dll compile time errors.

For the second part of your question, you can look here : [Reference disappear upon debug/build (C#, VB.NET, VS2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260592/reference-disappear-upon-debug-build-c-vb-net-vs2010)

Comment: The second question I am using the same .NET 4.6.1 for all projects (and not the client version).

Comment: The problem is I get ~4000 build errors all highlighted in red text. It also doesn't recover most of the time, I had to remove the reference and add it again. As I have ~4000 build errors I can't find the actual real error among the noise. This is not normal behaviour in my other visual studio projects.

Answer (score 0):

If project A, B, C and D depend on Z and building Z fails then all the other projects will also fail. This could be due to one single error but yes, now you will have many more errors than just one.

If you want, you can use the [StopOnFirstBuildError](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EinarEgilsson.StopOnFirstBuildError) extension so that if project Z fails, none of the other projects (dependents) will be attempted.

Comment: The problem is I get ~4000 build errors all highlighted in red text. It also doesn't recover most of the time, I had to remove the reference and add it again. As I have ~4000 build errors I can't find the actual real error among the noise. This is not normal behavior in my other visual studio projects.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get these chain effect build errors?

For this question, that because the typo error in root of the dependency `Library3`, just like the C.Dhruv and CodingYoshi said. Due to the typo error, the project `Library3` can not be build successfully. The `.dll` file `ClassLibrary3.dll` will not generate successfully, so other projects which reference it will throw the error:

```
> reference could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?)
```

Besides, you have multiple references, so you may get ~4000 build errors. I think you have already known the answer for this question. Now you question should be:

> I have ~4000 build errors I can't find the actual real error among the
>   noise. This is not normal behavior in my other visual studio projects.

Although there are ~4000 build errors in the error list window, but most of those errors should be build error not Intellisense error(detect the typo error), so we could use filter `Intellisense Only` on the error list to filter the Intellisense error:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue I have is the build errors become intellisense errors, eg basically my entire .cs file becomes red with annoying popups everywhere saying (do you want to add a reference?) making the file impossible to edit once I get any build errors at all. This is not normal behavior.

Comment: Filtering the errors is handy though, is this new to VS2017?

Comment: Can you read my edit and confirm if this is a problem with mixing the CSPROJ formats?

Comment: When I create a new test sample with old CSPROJ format for Library1,2,3, I still got the error for missing reference. To confirm, please try to clean solution before build it and make sure the filter is `Build + intellisense` not `Intellisense Only`.

Comment: @rolls, Filtering the errors is not a new feature to VS 2017. I'm not sure what specify version of VS2015 this feature is added to, but this function already exists in VS2015 update3. It very helpful us to filter the build error and intellisense errors. If this feature can help you get rid of ~4000 errors, you can you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: It is helpful but it is not the answer. The issue only occurs with mixing new and old csproj formats. For some reason it randomly loses my project references and they do not return until I manually delete and add the reference again, this causes the 4000+ red line errors that do not go away even with a clean.

Comment: In my test sample, I have not seen that random behavior. Would you mind share me a test sample to reproduce this issue?

Comment: It is a very large project with lots of IP. I will see if I can strip out code and make a public one.