# Namespace cannot be found in one form but it can in others in the same project VB VS2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm having an issue here which I can't resolve. I can't include the namespace which is correct because visual studio correct it into another namespace wich is incorrect. But in other forms in the same project it doesn't have the same behavior.I have checked that my project is configured in `.NET 4` and I have restart it and nothing happens. What's going on?
Could you please help me?

`Imports ProjectName.BusinessLogicLayer` -> This is the correct namespace

`Imports Projectname.BusinessLogicLayer` -> This is the incorrect

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 refuses to compile a namespace, says it doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785302/vs2010-refuses-to-compile-a-namespace-says-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Thank you very much because I resolved my problem Nidzaaa! I found the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785302/vs2010-refuses-to-compile-a-namespace-says-it-doesnt-exist

Comment: Click right on the file->Properties->Build Actions -> Choose Content, not Compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve my proble with Nidzaaa help! The answer is: Click right on the file->Properties->Build Actions -> Choose Content, not Compile